Subtitle shown wrong in ng-circle-progress
I have an Ionic app, and I've incorporated ng-circle-progress into one of its pages. I've included the following code:
<circle-progress *ngIf="workouts[currentIndex].video_en === 'Done'"
[percent]="100"
[outerStrokeWidth]="outerStrokeWidth"
[outerStrokeColor]="outerStrokeColor"
[innerStrokeWidth]="innerStrokeWidth"
[innerStrokeColor]="innerStrokeColor"
title="100%"
titleFontSize="25"
subtitleFontSize="20"
subtitle="{{ 'done' | translate }}"
[showBackground]="showBackground"
[animation]="animation"
[showUnits]=false
></circle-progress>

It functions perfectly in English on both Android and iOS. However, when I switch to Arabic language, half of the word appears on the same line as the title, while the other half appears on a new line.
Screenshot 1, Screenshot 2
The title and subtitle should be each one in separate line
